# OAuthErrors when trying to read a Facebook Page's messages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I am trying to read the inbox and outbox of a Facebook Page.  My first approach was to try to directly access the inbox of a `page` node. The URI below indicates how I tried to get it:

`/{page-id}/inbox`

Here is the error message:

> You can only access the \"inbox\" connection for the current user.

Then I tried to access the `conversations` and `threads` edges as suggested in some places like so:

`/{page-id}/conversations`

`/{page-id}/threads`

Both URIs produce the following error:

> (#298) You must be a developer of the application

I couldn't figure out what is wrong at all? There are some bug reports to Facebook, related to "#(298)", which were reported a few months ago but I can't believe it hasn't been fixed so far.

Any alternative approach is welcome.

Comment: `/pageid/conversations` works for me, provided I use a page access token.

Comment: (Posting on behalf of @Dennis t): Error #298 occurs for the conversations & threads edges even after creating a page access token with the read_mailbox & read_page_mailboxes permissions which are required as per an error message and the docs respectively. Then I tried it with all available permissions, still no luck. Finally, I gave the developer role to the current user which didn't work either.

Answer (score 3):

This problem happens if you use a user access token instead of a page access token.

I was doing this in the [Facebook Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and I thought I was using the page access token but I wasn't. When I ran `{page-id}/conversations?access_token={page_access_token}` from the API Explorer, it had the `{user_access_token}` in the *Access Token* field at the top. This was being sent in the actual request that the Explorer sent (as seen in Chrome's dev tools). I.e., the API Explorer was ignoring the `{page_access_token}` I entered and was using the value in the *Access Token* field.

Clearing the *Access Token* field or entering the `{page_access_token}` in that field resulted in the intended `{page_access_token}` being sent. Doing some of the steps in the browser vs the API Explorer showed me the way.

These are the steps to resolve the issue:

1. **Get a user access token:** with [`manage_pages`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/accounts#readperms) and [`read_page_mailboxes`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/conversations#readperms) permissions* by clicking *Get Access Token* from the API Explorer and selecting the specified permissions or visiting the URL below.

   ```
   https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={app-id}&redirect_uri={redirect-uri}&request_type=token&scope=manage_pages,read_page_mailboxes
   ```
2. **Get a page access token:** by running `/me/accounts` from the API Explorer or by vising the URL below.

   ```
   https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/me/accounts?method=GET&format=json&suppress_http_code=1&access_token={user-access-token}
   ```
3. **Get conversations:** Use the page access token (paste it in the *Access Token* field if using the API Explorer) from the above step to get conversations** by running `/{page-id}/conversations` or by vising the URL below.

   ```
   https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/{page-id}/conversations?method=GET&format=json&suppress_http_code=1&access_token={page-access-token}
   ```

* `read_mailbox` permission is not required, contrary to what I said in my comment above. Actually, the error message was incorrect, attempting to access Page edges with a user access token incorrectly gives user access errors instead of invalid Page access token errors.

** The user must be an admin of the Facebook Page to access its conversations.